# How can I write a paragraph with bullet points using Flutter?

Tags: text, flutter, bulletedlist

Using HTML I can add a bullet points to a paragraph like this:

```html
<ul>
   <li> example </li>
   <li> example </li>
   <li> example </li>
<ul>
```

How can I write bullet point form in Flutter?

```
new Text(''),
```

Comment: `•` is a character. Why not just use that inside your `Text` ?

Comment: Oooh, then use a Column widget to align them.

Comment: the `flutter_markdown` package might do this

Comment: Copy and use inside Text. `•` or `●`

Answer (score 52):

If you don't want to download another library (e.g. flutter_markdown), and one or more of your list items have lengthy text that spans several rows, I'd go with Raegtime's answer. However, since it assumes a string with line breaks, I want to make a version for a list with strings, which is a more common scenario. In the code below, `Column` makes the list items come on different rows, and `Row` makes the bullet points have empty space below themselves.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UnorderedList extends StatelessWidget {
  UnorderedList(this.texts);
  final List<String> texts;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var widgetList = <Widget>[];
    for (var text in texts) {
      // Add list item
      widgetList.add(UnorderedListItem(text));
      // Add space between items
      widgetList.add(SizedBox(height: 5.0));
    }

    return Column(children: widgetList);
  }
}

class UnorderedListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  UnorderedListItem(this.text);
  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("• "),
        Expanded(
          child: Text(text),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

We can use it as such:

```
UnorderedList([
    "What conclusions can we draw from the implementation?",
    "Are there any changes that need to be introduced permanently?"
])
```

And get the result:
[image: Picture of example result]

Comment: I implemented basically the same thing. Came here to find CrossAxisAlignment within the row as the last missing piece! Good work.

Answer (score 19):

Using markdown for this is overkill. Using `•` character is by far easier.

If you're too lazy to copy paste the character, here's a custom `Text` that does it for you:

```
class Bullet extends Text {
  const Bullet(
    String data, {
    Key key,
    TextStyle style,
    TextAlign textAlign,
    TextDirection textDirection,
    Locale locale,
    bool softWrap,
    TextOverflow overflow,
    double textScaleFactor,
    int maxLines,
    String semanticsLabel,
  }) : super(
          '• ${data}',
          key: key,
          style: style,
          textAlign: textAlign,
          textDirection: textDirection,
          locale: locale,
          softWrap: softWrap,
          overflow: overflow,
          textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
          maxLines: maxLines,
          semanticsLabel: semanticsLabel,
        );
}
```

Comment: It does not align long text message to right side of bullet icon. Any suggestion for long text? Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

I would better use utf-code. For list I think more comfortably will be something like:

```
class DottedText extends Text {
  const DottedText(String data, {
    Key key,
    TextStyle style,
    TextAlign textAlign,
    TextDirection textDirection,
    Locale locale,
    bool softWrap,
    TextOverflow overflow,
    double textScaleFactor,
    int maxLines,
    String semanticsLabel,
  }) : super(
    '\u2022 $data',
    key: key,
    style: style,
    textAlign: textAlign,
    textDirection: textDirection,
    locale: locale,
    softWrap: softWrap,
    overflow: overflow,
    textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
    maxLines: maxLines,
    semanticsLabel: semanticsLabel,);
}
```

Comment: It does not align long text message to right side of bullet icon. Any suggestion for long text? Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh if your text contains more than 1 line - I guess, you'd better use Row widget, which contains dot as first child and text as second one

Comment: Yes dear, I implemented the same because there was no other in-built solution.

Answer (score 12):

I tried using [flutter_markdown](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_markdown#-readme-tab-) and it seems to work. And of course you can change it to numbered/ordered or unordered list as you want.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter_markdown/flutter_markdown.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(Demo());


class Demo extends StatelessWidget {
  final testData = ["Example1", "Example2", "Example3", "Example100"];



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _markDownData = testData.map((x) => "- $x\n").reduce((x, y) => "$x$y");

    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
        child: Markdown(data: _markDownData)),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: It does not align long text message to right side of bullet icon. Any suggestion for long text? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

@Snurrig - Excellent answer. Works great! Thanks a lot!

Modified it to create an ordered/numbered list, as well.
See below:

```
class OrderedList extends StatelessWidget {
  OrderedList(this.texts);
  final List<dynamic> texts;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var widgetList = <Widget>[];
    int counter = 0;
    for (var text in texts) {
      // Add list item
      counter++;
      widgetList.add(OrderedListItem(counter, text));
      // Add space between items
      widgetList.add(SizedBox(height: 5.0));
    }

    return Column(children: widgetList);
  }
}

class OrderedListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  OrderedListItem(this.counter, this.text);
  final int counter;
  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("$counter. "),
        Expanded(
          child: Text(text),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you do not require markdowns everywhere, and just want to use them in one or two places, then adding a package or writing that much code for it is not a suitable idea.

You can copy the **DOT** from websites like **emojipedia** and paste it in front of your text.

here is an example:

```
Text("⚈ Provide, operate, and maintain our website"),
```

Comment: ● cleaner version

Answer (score 2):

you can use like this:

```
Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                '\u2022',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  height: 1.55,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 5,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: Text(
                    str,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    softWrap: true,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                      height: 1.55,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LineSplitter`, `Row`, `Column`, and the ASCII bullet point. All u need is a String with linebreaks.

```
String myStringWithLinebreaks = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3";
```

**Example in a ListTile**

```
 ListTile(
                  title: Text("Title Text"),
                  subtitle: 
                    Column(
                      children: LineSplitter.split(myStringWithLinebreaks).map((o) {
                    return Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("• "),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Text(o),
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  }).toList())),
```

Answer (score 1):

This will add bullet. Use it in a row with text.

```
Container(width: 10, height: 10, decoration: 
BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.black),),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Row(
   children: [
             _buildBullet(),
              const SizedBox(width: 5),
              _buildText(),
              ],
  ),

  SizedBox _buildBullet() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 7,
      width: 7,
      child: TextButton(
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF8B407),
          shape: const CircleBorder(),
        ),
        child: const Text(''),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    );
  }

  Text _buildText() {
    return const Text(
      'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create one widget which will take take and return bullet text. you can use this widget.

```
class BulletText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  const BulletText({
    super.key,
    required this.text,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      "• $text",
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
        
        
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can Use This anywhere you want like this

```
BulletText(text: "Scrap cars"),
```