# Flutter extends Stepper class

Tags: dart, flutter

I still new with Dart language.

I want to create a custom Stepper class with `extends` current Stepper class. The reason why I need to create custom Stepper because I need to override function `_buildHorizontal`

Current workaround:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomStepper extends Stepper {


  CustomStepper({
    Key key,
    @required Step steps,
    ScrollPhysics physics,
    StepperType type = StepperType.vertical,
    int currentStep = 0,
    ValueChanged<int> onStepTapped,
    VoidCallback onStepContinue,
    VoidCallback onStepCancel,
    ControlsWidgetBuilder controlsBuilder,
  }) : assert(steps != null),
       assert(type != null),
       assert(currentStep != null),
       super(key: key);
}
```

My question is, how to override `_buildHorizontal` in a right way?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: @MiguelRuivo I am trying to customise the Stepper such as stepper header color, dash color, etc.

Comment: No. That's not possible. Instead make an issue/PR

Answer (score 0):

You can see [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/stepper.dart) the colors that are being used by default by the `Stepper` that are being get from the `Theme`, such as primary color, accent color and so on.

If you want to change it *only* for that stepper, a more convenient approach is by wrapping it in a `Theme` and override those properties only for that widget, such as:

```
Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
          accentColor: Colors.blueAccent
        ),
        child: Stepper()
)
```

Otherwise, the best way is to copy the source of the `Stepper` for your own custom widget and tweak it for your needs.

Comment: By using `ThemeData`, it is still not enough for me. I still can't figure to change black color (the background) to red. See image https://imgur.com/QvWb7fy.

Futhermore, I cannot adjust the `padding` in the Stepper due value of the padding is hardcoded in the class. See image https://imgur.com/5MSuIzn

Comment: You can just copy the class and tweak it yourself. For the time being is one of the reliable solutions.

Comment: Did you suggest to duplicate `stepper.dart`, give a new name, and modify the code from the duplicated .dart? I am looking forward for a solution like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52659964/4358651